# Selenium-python: The value inside an element is not printed even though the element is presented

Tags: python, html, string, selenium, void

I have a simple piece of element as below. I'd like to print the text inside the code (54.98) using python-selenium, but I get empty string as output.

```html
<p class="class1 ng-binding">
  54.98
  <img alt="" title="" src="imgs/icons/image.png" ng-src="imgs/icons/image.png">
</p>
```

I have tried *WebDriverWait* to make sure the text is loaded and presented. Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
value = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "class1"))) 
value1 = value.text 
value2 = value.get_attribute('textContent')
value3 = value.get_attribute('innerHTML')
value4 = value.tag_name
```

and the results after printing each element:

```
value1 :
value2 :
value3 : <img src="imgs/icons/image.png" ng-src="imgs/icons/image.png" alt="" title="">
value4 : p
```

I don't know what else I should do!

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I am guessing because the text is populated by angular model, which by the time the element is ready -- the text isn't. You may try to wait until both "class1" and text != "" conditions met

Comment: How many `class1` elements are there on the page? How do you know?

Comment: `element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class1")` 
`numOfElements = len(element)`
print  "number of elements have Class1 is: " + str(numOfElements)  please run these code and see how many element has Class1 are there in your page?

Comment: I actually found out that the string is empty because my page is not loaded completely. It takes 2 seconds so that number get loaded. I set self.driver.implicitly_wait(3000) and still doesn't wait!